# connect the db and get the data with the headers in the table with pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm trying to get the data table from sql with headers but getting exception like 'params' arg () can be only a tuple or a dictionary.

Tried `cursor.execute(select * from table_name where ID=  %s', a)` but getting results like

```
| 0    | 1    | 2    | 3    |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1    | abc  | abc  | abc  |
| 2    | qwe  | qwe  | qwe  |
```

not getting the header name.

this is what I've tried. Any idea how to fetch with headers.

```
db = pd.read_sql_query("select * from table where ID= %(s) ", con, params=[a])
```

expecting results

```
| ID   | name | place | DOB  |
| ---- | ---- | ----- | ---- |
| 1    | abc  | abc   | abc  |
| 2    | qwe  | qwe   | qwe  |
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got the solution.

```
params = {
        'accountID': accountIDParam,
            }
data=pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=params, parse_dates=None, chunksize=None)
```